# Compiling C file with MingW in Windows: The system cannot execute the specified program

Tags: c, windows, gcc, command-line, mingw

The C file compiles perfectly fine as long as it's only:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )  {
  printf( "Hello, world without a new line" );
  return 0;
}
```

and it outputs "Hello, without a new line."

However, as I add more code to my program such as:

```
printf( "Hello, world with a new line\n" );
```

and I try to compile it like this:

```
gcc filename.c -o filename.exe
```

then I receive the message "The system cannot execute the specified program."

I checked if the PATH in the environment variables is there for MingW/bin, I opened and closed applications if it was a memory issue, I have the McAfee antivirus installed.

Comment: You receive that error when you compile the code using the command line you've shown or when you try to execute the compiled program? If the problem is executing the compiled program I'd check your antivirus to see if it is quarantining the file.

Comment: It's the second. The error message come whes I try to run filename.exe. I will check the Antivirus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will enable additional warnings which might help identify the issue.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o filename.exe filename.c
```

or you can try it disabling your antivirus.

or try with this.

```
gcc filename.c -o filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `gcc filename.c` without specifying which `.exe` needs to be created.
It will create `a.out` file and then run this file to get output.